# Can you remap REL_HWHEEL to BTN_* events or key combination using hwdb?

Tags: wayland, libinput

I have a mouse (Logitech M705) that features a 4-way scroll wheel.
The left/right press are basically buttons, so not like an actual horizontal scroll wheel.
Since I have no use for the horizontal scrolling functionality (and surely not by single button press events), I would like to use these for something else, e.g. to navigate tabs in a browser (typically CTRL+PgUp or PgDown).
Now in X11, this is rather easy using e.g. imwheel, but on Wayland, it seems more complicated.
While the rest of the key trigger EV_MSC/EV_KEY events, spitting out a scan code that can be used in KEYBOARD_KEY remappings, the REL_HWHEEL buttons trigger EV_REL and then +1 or -1 when testing with evtest.
i.e. for the left mouse button:

```
Event: time 1674593064.411235, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1674593064.411235, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
```

For scroll wheel left:

```
Event: time 1674593069.069576, type 2 (EV_REL), code 6 (REL_HWHEEL), value -1
Event: time 1674593069.069576, type 2 (EV_REL), code 12 (REL_HWHEEL_HI_RES), value -120
```

Can I still remap them using a custom hwdb file and if so, how?
Either directly to a key combination or to something like BTN_EXTRA2 and BTN_EXTRA3.

evtest also tells me this about the device:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0x101b version 0x111
Input device name: "Logitech M705"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 275 (BTN_SIDE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
    Event code 277 (BTN_FORWARD)
    Event code 278 (BTN_BACK)
    Event code 279 (BTN_TASK)
    Event code 280 (?)
    Event code 281 (?)
    Event code 282 (?)
    Event code 283 (?)
    Event code 284 (?)
    Event code 285 (?)
    Event code 286 (?)
    Event code 287 (?)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
    Event code 11 (REL_WHEEL_HI_RES)
    Event code 12 (REL_HWHEEL_HI_RES)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
```

Cheers,
Bernd

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue for libinput. Maybe the developers can help.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/868

I got the same issue with a *"Logitech M500s"*.

Comment: As I already commented on the libinput issue, I'm now using solaar to switch the functionality. libratbag also provides that option, but for me it's currently failing to use the mouse properly due to a bug, hence using solaar. 

Unfortunately, this is not persistent across boots. I have to start solaar once at every boot to switch the "HWHEEL" functionality. Just starting and closing it is enough. Have yet to find a way to properly automate this during system boot.